# calender.getTimeInMilliseconds does not work with alarm manager object

Tags: android, date, notifications, calendar, alarmmanager

I want to start a notification at startTime and end at the endTime specified by the user. Also the count of notifications is specified to be shown in the same time slot. I have divided count with startTime and endTime to get the intervals of time.

Now I am getting intervals correct but the notification is not getting triggered.

```
  public static List<Calendar> setAlarmTimeList(String startTime, String endTime,
            int howMany) {
        List<Calendar> times = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date start = dateFormat.parse(startTime);
            Date end = dateFormat.parse(endTime);
            long minutes = ((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000 / 60) /
                    (howMany - 1);
            Calendar calobj;
            for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {

                calobj = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
                calobj.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(start).split(":")[0]));
                calobj.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(start).split(":")[1]));
                calobj.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) (i * minutes));
                calobj.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                times.add(calobj);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("timesList", times.toString());
        return times;
    }
```

This is my function to get the time intervals. I get the list like below :

```
 D/timesList: [Tue May 19 16:21:00 GMT+05:30 2020, Tue May 19 16:24:00 GMT+05:30 2020, Tue May 19 16:27:00 GMT+05:30 2020, Tue May 19 16:30:00 GMT+05:30 2020, Tue May 19 16:33:00 GMT+05:30 2020, Tue May 19 16:36:00 GMT+05:30 2020, Tue May 19 16:39:00 GMT+05:30 2020, Tue May 19 16:42:00 GMT+05:30 2020, Tue May 19 16:45:00 GMT+05:30 2020, Tue May 19 16:48:00 GMT+05:30 2020]
```

I am showing notification like :

public static void showNotification(
            List timeList, Context context,
            String quote
    ) {

```
    for (Calendar date : timeList) {
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, MyNewIntentReceiver.class);

        notifyIntent.putExtra("title", context.getString(R.string.app_name));

        final int random = new Random().nextInt();
        notifyIntent.putExtra("notify_id", random);

        notifyIntent.putExtra(
                "quote",
                quote
        );
        int randomInt = new Random().nextInt(1000);

        notifyIntent.putExtra("requestCode",randomInt);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                randomInt,
                notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT

        );

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        Log.d("date",String.valueOf(date.getTimeInMillis()));

     /*   long afterTwoMinutes = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000;*/
        long afterTwoMinutes = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Log.d("aftertwoMinutes",String.valueOf(afterTwoMinutes));

        long datetimer = date.getTimeInMillis();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle
                    (AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                           date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        else
            alarmManager.setExact
                    (AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                            date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    Log.d("notificationIntentSet", "Utils, pending intent set");
}
```

Erlier I used Date object list as it was not working I tried to use Calender object list. But both are not working here.

Notification does not get triggered. If I set
 /*   long afterTwoMinutes = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000;*/
It worked.

Also not working with     long afterTwoMinutes = System.currentTimeMillis();

Please suggest thank you..

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Maybe you can demonstrate your problem with a minimal example, 10 lines of code or fewer? [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).